# Data binding of type of Date Class. "2010/01/02" binds correctly, but "2010-01-02" does not

Tags: spring, http, jsp, spring-mvc

I found that, by default when I using Spring MVC, "2010/01/02" binds correctly, but "2010-01-02" does not.

I know Spring has some useful binding mechanisms like initBinder. However, in this question I want to know where is the rule defined. Does anyone know that for example RFC documents of HTTP or Spring references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just coincidence.

Spring MVC can implicitly convert input parameters to model objects via their single-argument constructor that takes `String` (if model objects have such constructors). `Date` has this constructor, though it's deprecated, so that this behaviour is determined by behaviour of that constructor.

Comment: I am afraid I'm not exactly sure.. Do you mean this rule is not relative to Spring and constructor of Date class has something regular expression like "yyyy/mm/dd"?

Comment: @yusaku: Exactly. You can see it by looking at the stacktrace when value can't be bound. Behaviour of the constructor is described in its javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html